# International student in the USA reselling in europe

Tags: united-states, non-resident, f1-student-visa, government, student

I am a student studying in the USA and have a study visa. I have a business in Germany with a partner of mine. What i'm wondering is, if there are problems with my visa or if I risk something if i buy products in america, I ship them to Germany and resell them through our company there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i'm wondering is, if there are problems with my visa or if I risk something if i buy products in america, I ship them to Germany and resell them through our company there?

Yes. You're performing work for which you do not have employment authorization in the US, meaning you're violating your visa conditions.

Under a student visa in the US you can get an employment authorization to work for up to 20 hours a week on campus or as part of a CPT/OPT program, in each of this cases you'd need an endorsement from the international students' office of your school.